# Whats is the difference between function component vs class component in react?

Tags: reactjs, components

I don't understand the difference between function component vs class component..It would be glad for me if someone explain it in a simple way.

Comment: functional components have better performance

Comment: Kindly go through the React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

function component vs class component

1.functional component uses less code than class components.
2.both have different set of life cycle methods.
-funtional based- useEffect,
-class based - componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount, etc
3.use can use react hooks on funtional based but you can't in class based,
4.functional component is more efficient.
5.functional component is light weight.

Comment: I am a beginner in react js.So, which one (function based or class based) should i use ?

Comment: function based components. but you should have knowlege about  class based components